# Optional Argument code compiles in .NET 3.5. Why?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, optional-parameters

This piece of code compiles OK in VS 2010 in a framework 3.5 project (I triple checked that)

```
    public LoggingClient(string uri = "net.msmq://localhost/logging"){...}
```

Why? I see nothing in the C# 4 spec ([doc version](http://download.microsoft.com/download/7/E/6/7E6A548C-9C20-4C80-B3B8-860FAF20887A/CSharp%204.0%20Specification.doc)), section 21.1, that says this should be backwardly compatible. How is it that I get no compilation error? Will this fail silently in some circumstances?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you use Optional Parameters in code targeting .Net 3.5? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210679/can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-code-targeting-net-3-5)

Comment: In general, there is no relationship between the C# language version and the .NET version.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Project + Properties, Build tab, scroll down, Advanced.  You can change the Language Version to "C# 3.0" if you prefer to maintain source code compatibility.

But yes, you are using the C# 4.0 compiler in VS2010, regardless of the target .NET version you use.  The output of the compiler, IL, hasn't changed in .NET 4.0.  No, you can't use *dynamic*, it requires a .NET 4.0 only support assembly (Microsoft.CSharp.dll)

Answer (score 3):

Optional parameters are merely syntactic sugar - if you don't specify it at the call site, the compiler fills it the default value. There's no dependancy on the .NET framework itself to do anything.

See also [Can you use optional parameters in code targeting .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210679/can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-code-targeting-net-3-5)