# C# 3.5 Optional and DefaultValue for parameters

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5

I am using C# .net 3.5 to build an application. I have been working with optional parameter attributes in .net 4.0 with no problems. I did notice that with 3.5 there is the option (workaround) to add the following attributes to your method like so:

```
    public static void MethodName(string name, [Optional][DefaultValue(null)]string placeHolder)
    {

    }
```

Even though I have added the attributes to the method, if I try and call it like so:

```
     MethodName("test");
```

The compiler will complain that it is looking for two parameters instead of one. Is it actually possible to do this using C# .net 3.5? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Same thing happen with us.Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Optional parameters are C# 4.0 language feature so it doesn't matter which framework you are targeting, but you have to compile it using VS 2010 or newer.

Use this syntax in VS 2010 or newer:

```
public static void MethodName(string name, string placeHolder = null)
{
    // body
}
```

Or this in older one:

```
public static void MethodName(string name, string placeHolder)
{
    // body
}

public static void MethodName(string name)
{
    MethodName(name, null);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried setting the framework version to 3.5 in VS2010, but it still throws a compilation error. "Arguments Mismatch".

Comment: I was also looking for a way to do this without having to do it the old skool way - looks like I might have to!

Comment: In project properties go to build tab, advanced and set the language to C# 4.0. That should work even when .NET 3.5 framework is set.

Comment: I tried setting the framework version to 4 & 3.5 in VS2010, but it still throws a compilation error when I use it in VS2008. "Arguments Mismatch"

Comment: And oh - you mentioned you use it in VS2008. It can't work. Only VS2010 can compile C# 4.0 code. That's what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 6):

The `Optional` attribute has been available since C# 1.0, and is used when interoperating with external code, it has no effect on method calls in your own code.

As there is no optional parameters in C# 3, you can use overloading instead:

```
public static void MethodName(string name, string placeHolder) {
  ...
}

public static void MethodName(string name) {
  MethodName(name, null);
}
```

(Side note: There is no C# version 3.5, that is a framework version.)

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the following StackOverflow thread:
[C# Optional Parameters in .net 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210679/can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-code-targeting-net-3-5)

No use in copy pasting everything which has been said there, as the thread covers pretty much everything.
Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I did see that question - unfortunately I tried setting the framework version to 3.5 in VS2010, but it still throws a compilation error. "Arguments Mismatch"