# Can a MonoDevelop user benefit from optional parameters while still targeting at 3.5?

Tags: mono, monodevelop, optional-parameters, dmcs

As stated in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1210679), thanks to some compilation trickery, Visual Studio 2010 allows a project targeting at .Net 3.5 to benefit from optional parameters.

Is it possible to achieve similar behavior with MonoDevelop 2.6b1?

**EDIT:**
This problem doesn't however affect `xbuild` which can successfully leverage `dmcs` (C#4.0 compiler) to target a 3.5 profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=566247
Once it is marked as resolved, you know your request can be satisfied too.