# C# CLR/Compiling Question

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, clr

I posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375240/compiler-version-vs-net-framework-version-scenario-with-asp-net-applications) question yesterday asking about a C# 4 client deploying an ASP.NET application to a .NET 3.5 target server and weather C# 3 on the server compiled something or C# 4 on the client.

That scenario was with optional parameters. I know optional parameters have been supported since like .NET 1.1. Why is it that C# 3 compiled IL code is not be able to call C#4 compiled IL code using optional parameters?

Does C# 3 just ignore the optional attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right... The IL is just decorated w/ OptionalAttributes, but it's the calling compiler that decides what to do...

From Richter:

> Now, when a compiler sees that you have code calling a method that is missing some arguments, the compiler can ensure that you've omitted optional argumements, grab their default values out of metadata, and embed them...

So it's the **CALLING** compiler deciding what to do w/ the optionals, not the called c# 4.0 IL...

More on edge cases and how it's the calling method that decides value can be found from Lippert, @ http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/05/16/optional-argument-corner-cases-part-three.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Optional parameters were introduced to C# only in version 4.0.
(They were available in .NET earlier in VB).

Comment: I am asking this question from the perspective of the IL Code. The way I understand it the optional parameters are applied using attributes that end up in the generated IL code. So my basically I am asking for clarification of what happens when C# 3 generated IL code tries to call code using Optional parameters in this case C# 4 generated IL, but I am guessing the same would hold for the earlier VB optionals i.e. C# 3 calling into VB generated IL code using optional or C# 3 calling into C# 4 generated IL code.

Answer (score 1):

My simple guess would be because the Base Class Libraries are different? This makes the difference between C# 3.* and 4.* much bigger than say 2.* vs 3.* as the latter used the same BCL.

Not sure though.