# Compile Error "Default parameter specifiers are not permitted" with .Net 4.0- Project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

All of a sudden today my project started giving me this error:

Default parameter specifiers are not permitted

The project is supposed to be compiled with .Net 4.0.The WEb.config file has 4.0 specified:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
```

What could possibly be going on here? Any help or places to look would be appreciated.

**UPDATED:**

I tried changing the .Net Framework Target to 3.0 and even 2.0, saving the solution and then back to 4.0 and 4.5 but it didn't work. I think I've read the same "fixes" that everyone else has with no luck unfortunately.

Comment: Per this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9042847/1346943), have you tried toggling to 3.5 and then back to 4.0?

Answer (score 0):

i too have the same problem.my project is also targeting 4.0 and not 3.5 or below.

I toggled it to 3.5 and then back to 4.0 and then the error went away.

May this will work for u.