# No overload for method takes 2 arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, optional-parameters

I've created a dll .

The dll had a method,which is having 4 optional parameters and 2 required parameters.

When i try to call the method in VS2010, it's working well and good even though i supply only 2 required parameters.

But when i tried to call the method in VS2008, it is showing error message 'No overload for method takes 2 arguments'.

Do i need to pass the 4 optional parameters values as `null` inorder to get rid of this ?

Please help

Thanks,

Comment: "Visual C# 2010 **introduces** named and optional argument(...)" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: it is only available for c#>=4.0

Comment: @L.B that's not true. I have a C# .NET Framework 3.5 assembly declaring optional parameters just fine in VS 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional parameters are new to Visual Studio 2010 so aren't supported in 2008. You need to explictly pass arguments for the optional parameters.

[Can you use optional parameters in code targeting .NET 3.5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210679/can-you-use-optional-parameters-in-code-targeting-net-3-5)

Answer (score 0):

Optional parameters is a C# 4.0 feature so you won't be able to use it on C# 3.5. Send explicity the default value for those.

Comment: yes optional parameter was introduced in c# 4.0, you should target the .net fx 4.0 somehow in visual studio 2008

Comment: Optional parameters are a VS 2010 feature not a C# 4.0 feature. Therefore @SéddikLaraba 's answer wouldn't work either.